# HyperledgerFabric v1.0.0 *SampleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have encountered a problem while building my own chaincode.

Hypeledger Fabric version -v 1.0.0

```
>  cannot use new(SampleChaincode) (type *SampleChaincode) as type
> shim.Chaincode in argument to shim.Start:
>         *SampleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode (wrong type for Init method)
>                 have Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
>                 want Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response
```

I have try compiling in v0.6 fabric and it succeeded. However when i instantiate the chaincode, i received the same messages, probably because my blockchain is running on v1.0.0

**Hence is there a way to fix this??**

*this is my code*

```
func main() {

lld, _ := shim.LogLevel("DEBUG")
fmt.Println(lld)
logger.SetLevel(lld)
fmt.Println(logger.IsEnabledFor(lld))
err := shim.Start(new(SampleChaincode))
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("Could not start SampleChaincode")
} else {
    logger.Info("SampleChaincode successfully started")
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 1.0.0 the interface of chaincode has been changed to encapsulate the response within:

```
// A response with a representation similar to an HTTP response that can
// be used within another message.
type Response struct {
    // A status code that should follow the HTTP status codes.
    Status int32 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=status" json:"status,omitempty"`
    // A message associated with the response code.
    Message string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=message" json:"message,omitempty"`
    // A payload that can be used to include metadata with this response.
    Payload []byte `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=payload,proto3" json:"payload,omitempty"`
}
```

Hence the signature of the function in interface changed to:

```
// Chaincode interface must be implemented by all chaincodes. The fabric runs
// the transactions by calling these functions as specified.
type Chaincode interface {
    // Init is called during Instantiate transaction after the chaincode container
    // has been established for the first time, allowing the chaincode to
    // initialize its internal data
    Init(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response

    // Invoke is called to update or query the ledger in a proposal transaction.
    // Updated state variables are not committed to the ledger until the
    // transaction is committed.
    Invoke(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response
}
```

Hence the error message you've got:

> `cannot use new(SampleChaincode) (type *SampleChaincode) as type
>   shim.Chaincode in argument to shim.Start:
>           *SampleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode (wrong type for Init method)
>                   have Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
>                   want Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response`

Answer (score 2):

Right, the interfaces are different.
The v1.0 chaincode [interface](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L28-L38) differs than the v0.6 one.
Please take a look at the [following](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02/chaincode_example02.go) example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the share, i compared the v0.6 and v1.0.0 hyperledger fabric examples.

**v0.6** hyperledger fabric example:

```
func (t *SampleChaincode) Query(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
if function == "queryPatientInfo" {
    return queryPatientInfo(stub, args)
}
return nil, nil
```

vs

**v1.0.0** hyperledger fabric example:

```
func (t *SampleChaincode) Query(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
if function == "queryPatientInfo" {
    return queryPatientInfo(stub, args)
}
return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

also importing:

```
pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
```

i just thought i should share this :)